# scrapy:IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, scrapy

When I used the command line parameter to start a scrapy project `scrapy startproject TotalValue`, an error occurred  :

> IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
>   'TotalValue\TotalValue\settings. py.tmpl'".

`TotalValue` is the project name

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE] that demonstrates your problem. It is very difficult for people to help without seeing some code.

Comment: scrapy is a spider frame .After I install the frame, I want to creat a scrapy project to get some web data.when i input the  startproject commands ("scrapy startproject TotalValue") ,the IOError raise.no any other code.

Comment: i have resolved the problem when i reinstall the module of scrapy .thanks for you review. .

Comment: I'm getting this error when creating the project in a virtualbox shared folder. Host is windows 10, guest is Ubuntu 18.0.4